# Kotlin call a function without importing the file it's in

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin function that creates new Kotlin Objects in new files. Every new Kotlin Objects have a function in them called `registger`. I now want to execute this `register` function for every Object that was created in another file. I can get the name of every file with ease but I have no idea how to call these function without importing every file or how I automate the importing of all these files that were created.

Comment: Are you using a framework such as Spring? (That takes care of things like scanning for classes and making them available.)

Comment: Nah, I don't. I would really like doing it without a framework.